# Rails passing message to dynamic method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I want to dynamically have new_course_discussion_path(@discussable) or new_group_discussion_path(@discussable) depending on the @discussable class type. How do I pass the message (@discussable) in to this method? I tried:

```
"new_#{@discussable.class.to_s.downcase}_discussion_path".constantize(@discussable)
```

but this says "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)". I'm new to rails. Please help! Thanks.

Update:
Right now, the whole line is

```
= link_to '>New Discussion', "new_#{@discussable.class.to_s.downcase}_discussion_path".constantize(@discussable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
send "new_#{@discussable.class.to_s.downcase}_discussion_path", @discussable
```

The path helpers are *methods* not classes. They're accessible from controllers, views and helper methods and if you don't qualify the `send` call, it will invoke the method on self.

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work. here is what it says: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...nk_to '>New Discussion', send "new_#{@discussable.class.to_s...
They whole line is: '= link_to '>New Discussion', send "new_#{@discussable.class.to_s.downcase}_discussion_path", @discussable'

Comment: The way you're embedding the call to send in another method call, you need to include the parenthsis `send(...,@discussable)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Object.send method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999).

Comment: Thanks. But I stared at obj.send(symbol [, args...]) → obj for 3 minutes and still can't connect the solution with the documentation. I guess I'm still too shallow to navigate in the documentation. :)